# how to use object data from controller in JS to create a diagramm

Tags: javascript, java, spring, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I'm currently working on a Spring boot project, trying to display data from a REST API(https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/10808728/SzS8rjbc#intro) in a diagram. So far I have a route in my controller to get a JSON from a URL and convert it to a Java Objects. I would like to pass the Object to the View where I'm using Thymeleaf. I created the Models(Java Objects) as well. I tried to use ModelAndView but it didn't work out for me.

Java Controller:

```
package com.mario.countrycatalog.rescources;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.mario.countrycatalog.models.Corona.CoronaInformation;
import com.mario.countrycatalog.models.Country.CountryInformation;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class CountryCatalogResource {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    /**
     * API:
     * https://restcountries.eu/
     */
    public final String urlCountry = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/";
    /**
     * API:
     * https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/10808728/SzS8rjbc#intro
     */
    public final String urlCorona = "https://api.covid19api.com/";

    @RequestMapping("/countries")
    public List<CountryInformation> getAllCountries() {
        CountryInformation[] countries = restTemplate.getForObject(urlCountry + "all", CountryInformation[].class);

        assert countries != null;
        return Arrays.asList(countries);
    }

    // TODO: Get countryName from client inputfield
    @RequestMapping("/countries/{countryName}")
    public CountryInformation[] getCountry(@PathVariable String countryName, Model model) {
        try {
            // ggf Model raus
            model.addAttribute("countryName", countryName);
            // Json to Java Object
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            List<CountryInformation> cis = objectMapper.readValue(
                    new URL(urlCountry + "name/" + countryName),
                    new TypeReference<List<CountryInformation>>() {
            });

            // print borders from obj
            cis.forEach((CountryInformation element) -> {
                for (String border : element.getBorders()) {
                    System.out.println(border);
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return restTemplate.getForObject(urlCountry + "name/" + countryName, CountryInformation[].class);
    }


//------------------------------------------------------------------------
//I was working on the following two methods and was trying to pass the coronaInformation object to the view.


    @RequestMapping("/corona/summary")
    public CoronaInformation getAllCoronaInformations() {
        CoronaInformation coronaInformation = restTemplate.getForObject(urlCorona + "summary", CoronaInformation.class);
        assert coronaInformation != null;
        System.out.println(coronaInformation.getGlobal().getNewConfirmed());


        return coronaInformation;
    }

    // TODO: WIP
    @RequestMapping(value = "message", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView test() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("message/test");
        CoronaInformation coronaInformation = restTemplate.getForObject(urlCorona + "summary", CoronaInformation.class);

        mav.addObject("coronaTest", coronaInformation.getGlobal().getNewConfirmed());

        return mav;
    }

//    TODO: GET Live By Country All Status
    //TODO: GET Live By Country And Status After Date
}
```

JS File (chart-action.js):

```
  window.onload = function () {
  let ctx = document.getElementById('coronaChart');
  //let newConfirmed = [[${newConfirmed}]];
  //let totalConfirmed = [[${totalConfirmed}]];

  let coronaChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
      labels: [
        'Red',
        'Blue',
        'Yellow'
      ],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'My First Dataset',
//TODO: fill with data from corona API
        data: [150, 300, 100],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
          'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
          'rgb(255, 205, 86)'
        ],
        hoverOffset: 4
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    }
  });

}
```

HTML File (index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.0/chart.js"
            integrity="sha512-opXrgVcTHsEVdBUZqTPlW9S8+99hNbaHmXtAdXXc61OUU6gOII5ku/PzZFqexHXc3hnK8IrJKHo+T7O4GRIJcw=="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--    TODO: for future-->
    <!--    <link th:href="@{/styles/cssandjs/main.css}" rel="stylesheet" />-->
</head>
<body>
<script th:inline="javascript">
    let newConfirmed = [[${coronaTest}]];
    console.log(newConfirmed);
    let totalConfirmed = [[${coronaTest}]];
    $(document).ready(function() {
    buildChart(newConfirmed, totalConfirmed);
    });
</script>


<canvas id="coronaChart" width="100%" height="auto"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/chart-action.js}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not so sure if my attempt is right, maybe I'm on the wrong track.
I hope the code snippets are helping.

Comment: The external JS script file is not processed by Thymeleaf, so the Thymeleaf expressions it contains are not evaluated. Suggestion: (1) In your external JS file, convert `window.onload = function ()` to something like `function buildChart(newConfirmed, totalConfirmed)` - in other words, a regular function. (2) In your HTML file, create a "document ready" function in a `<script th:inline="javascript">` tag which calls the new `buildChart` function. You can create your two variables in that script tag first. Because this happens in your HTML file, it will be processed by Thymeleaf.

Comment: (And if you have a large number of parameters you need to pass to the external script, you can put them in a JS map, and pass that as a single parameter, to prevent things from becoming unwieldy.)

Comment: how can I add my variables to the buildChart?

`<script th:inline="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    buildChart();
    });
</script>
`

Comment: Like you do in your current code. `let newConfirmed = [[${newConfirmed}]];`. Then use `newConfirmed` as a parameter: `buildChart(newConfirmed);`.

Comment: I don't get the data from the backend, I think there is something wrong in the controller class (Java route).

Comment: You can [edit] your question to provide more information about the specific problem you are facing. But I would guess that there are already various SO questions (and answers) covering that. And if you cannot find a solution, please consider providing a [mre].

Comment: The thing is, that I get no error, but for some reason there is nothing showing on the View. So it seems there is a problem between the controller.class and the thymeleaf HTML file.

I will post the controller and the updated html file.

Comment: I could fix the problem, I had the wrong annotation in my Controller class it was on ```@RestController``` but it should be on ```@Controller``` and for the routes where I call the API I added ```@ResponseBody```